# Where should I store the VM files (config, snapshots, vhd) on a Hyper-V server?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd

By default the VHDs go into “C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks” and the config files go into “C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V”.

Should I leave them there?

Is it ok for the VHDs to be in a “Public” folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I do:

- I have pretty much always a RAID 10 for the Hyper-V host, 4 discs. Either BLack Scorpio (lower performance) or Velociraptors.
- 64gb base partition
- The rest is a second partion "V:"
- VM's live on V.
- Public is not ok - i mean, seriously, what for?

Comment: you don't want your server images on a public drive. I would keep the server images on a separate disk system of either raid 1 or raid 10 depending on your performance needs, snapshots I would store on a different drive  or storage server for backup and retrieval purposes. 

I guess the question to really ask is, what are you doing to begin with? Are you learning within a home environment or lab setup? Or is this going to be something that will go into production?

Comment: Well, normally the OS discs basically do nthing. After startup you can ignore them - as long as nothing else than hyper-v runs on them.The Raid 10 stops me from having to have more discs in. Me personally I do that with a lot of setups - sometimes quite high performance (32gb server, 4 cores, running sql server with directly mapped discs for the real data).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'll want your VMs on a disk subsystem that is redundant and shared with every member of the Hyper-V cluster.  This will almost never be C:.

Comment: Yeah. Assumingthere I a cluster. Assuming you have the funds to do replication and pay the disc space twice. Assuming Hyper-V internal replication is not enough for you. THat is a lot of "assumes" for a question obviously about a smaller setup.